# angularJS pagination by date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I just started using angularJS and I'm wondering about the best practices of a date pagination. I've got a bunch of entries in my database that all have a creation_date field.

My goal is to use some sort of selector that would only display the entries for a particular month, and be able to change months.

I've thought of two ways to implement this :

client side by using a custom filter

server side with a /entries/:year/:month URL and only using angular for routing

Following angularJS best practices, which would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is is nothing to do with Angular specifically. 
If the amount of data that is available in database

- Is large or
- It would grow over time

Then server side is the only viable option.

Client side filter, needs all data on client before filtering can be done. So the decision very much boils down to how much data do you have and the growth pattern.